# Github Pages Subdirectory Files Not Showing Up

Tags: github, github-pages

I have a repository with an index.html file and subfolders containing other html files. The repository name is "parent-folder" and the repository contains "subfolder1", "subfolder2", etc.

Within the index.html, the code has links to the subfolders as, for example,"/subfolder1/subfolder1.html"

I put the repository up onto github pages so that I can access the index.html file as .github.io/parent-folder, but when I click the links on the page that are supposed to bring me to the subfolder1.html, it brings me to a 404 pages. I also have subfolders that contain images that I reference in index.html, which also do not show up.

How should I be including the subfolder references in my index.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

- either relative URLs:

  ```
  <a href="./subfolder1/aFile">SubFolder1</a>
  ```
- or absolute URLS:

  ```
  <a href="https://github.io/parent-folder/subfolder1/aFile">SubFolder1</a>
  ```

But consider also [using GitHub Action to  publish your site](https://github.blog/2022-08-10-github-pages-now-uses-actions-by-default/), using one of the [starter packs](https://github.com/actions/starter-workflows/tree/main/pages).

---

The [OP grapeporcupine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19489286/grapeporcupine) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73329550/github-pages-subdirectory-files-not-showing-up/73329660#comment129509420_73329660):

> My issue was that I was not including the "`.`" and "`..`" to reference the subfolders

Comment: Thank you that worked. My issue was that I was not including the "." and ".." to reference the subfolders

Comment: @grapeporcupine Thank you for your feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.